# Get last active control with ActiveControl, or with any method, and SendKeys to it

Tags: vb.net

I have a button that passes sendkeys to the textbox in focus. In this case, it is Textedit1

```
    'get current focused form.
    AppActivate(Process.GetCurrentProcess.Id)

    'set current focused textbox 
    TextEdit1.Focus() '<- is it possible to change this so that it gets the *LAST* selected control, then focus?



    'the character to be passed
    SendKeys.Send("B")
```

However, I have a lot of textboxes on my form, and it would be impractical to place code on the lostfocus on each textbox control in my form.

My plan is to get the *Last focused control* in my form which is the *last control clicked by the user before clicking this button*, set focus to it, then SendKeys.Send to it so that whatever the user clicks a control, I can pass a SendKeys to it.

How do you get the *last focused control*? is it possible with `ActiveControl`?

**EDIT**
I am making a software that is available for touch monitors, and a requirement is that I have an on screen keyboard dedicated for the software only. I cannot use OSK.

Comment: If you have the reference to the TextEdit control why do you need to call SendKeys? If you give us some more information on the overall objective of your app we might be able to suggest something productive

Comment: added the reason, and explaining the question's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private PreviousControl As Control
Private Sub doSet(ByVal parentCtr As Control)
    Dim ctr As Control
    For Each ctr In parentCtr.Controls
        AddHandler ctr.Leave, AddressOf meLeave
        doSet(ctr)
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub meLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    PreviousControl = DirectCast(sender, Control)
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    doSet(Me)
End Sub
Private Sub btn15_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    Dim strName As String
    strName = PreviousControl.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to stack overflow! Could you please edit your answer and add some text explaining what this code does and how it helps answer the posted question?